# How do I make UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator visible in orange color instead of gray color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iPhone development.I have created an application using `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`. I give the line like this:

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`;

It shows an indicator arrow in gray color. I want to display indicator in orange color instead of gray color. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `accessoryView` property of `UITableViewCell` to retrieve UIView object and add whatever you want into that view in whatever color you desire.