# How do I make UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator visible in orange color instead of gray color?

Tags: iphone

without Creating any of the uibutton(custom button with background image)in tableview cell.
I want to change the accessory indicator color from gray to orange.What should i do for that...

plz reply as soon as possible(plz answer me clearly or else i can't understand)...

i'm waiting for ur reply...

Thank u...

Comment: without creating UIButton or UIImageView as accessoryView of your UITableViewCell instance, it is impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423824/how-do-i-make-uitableviewcellaccessorydisclosureindicator-visible-in-orange-color/3423863#3423863

Comment: -1 duplicate of your own question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create a new UIView with a UIImageView inside it and then set that as the Accessory for the cell. So you'll need to create a image just like the default accessory but in the colour you want.

```
UIView* accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 50)];
    UIImageView* accessoryViewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NEWIMAGE.png"]];
    accessoryViewImage.center = CGPointMake(12, 25);
    [accessoryView addSubview:accessoryViewImage];
    [cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
    [accessoryViewImage release];
    [accessoryView release];
```

Comment: Thank u so much...OCTERMIRCTY

Answer (score 7):

There's a much easier solution to this:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theimage.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who are still stumbling upon this question, here's how to do it programmatically.

Create a UIView subclass, and override `drawRect:` with the following:

```
#define PADDING 4.f //give the canvas some padding so the ends and joints of the lines can be drawn with a mitered joint

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.f);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinMiter);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, PADDING, PADDING);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width - PADDING, self.frame.size.height/2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, PADDING, self.frame.size.height - PADDING);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This draws a stock indicator arrow. From here you can change the color, line width, etc.

To add the indicator view to your cell:

```
#define ACCESSORY_WIDTH 13.f
#define ACCESSORY_HEIGHT 18.f

cell.accessoryView = [[AccessoryIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - ACCESSORY_WIDTH - CELL_PADDING, self.frame.size.height/2 - ACCESSORY_HEIGHT/2, ACCESSORY_WIDTH, ACCESSORY_HEIGHT)];
```